# Parse .txt file to different arrays

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have .txt file with different data. All this data organize for 3 category. I need to get some data for 1st array, some for 2nd and another for 3rd. How to do this?

The .txt file contains part X, empty spaces and # (to separate text from 2nd and 3rd category)

```
part 1
some data for 1st array

part 2
some data for 2nd array#some data for 3rd array

part 3
some data for 1st array

part 4
some data for 2nd array#some data for 3rd array
```

At the same time, I need to gather data from each category:
from part 1 and 3, from part 2 and 4, after #

Right now I'm stuck, my code takes all data and I don't know what should I do next.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        String data = "";
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.phrases);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        if ( is!= null){
            try {
                while ((data=reader.readLine()) !=null){
                    sBuffer.append(data + "\n");
                }
                textView.setText(sBuffer);
                is.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete, what are your file format specs

Comment: Does your file really contain `partX` and empty lines? Also for now it looks like you only read each line to StringBuffer, but we still don't know what is stopping you from putting these lines (or parts of them after splitting) into arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your parse logic inside your while loop where you are reading one line per iteration.

You could do something like this inside your loop:

```
String[] parsedData = new String[3];
int parsingBlock = -1;
while ((data=reader.readLine()) !=null) {
    if (parsingBlock >= 0) {
        switch (parsingBlock) {
            case 0: parsedData[0] = data; break;
            case 1: {
                String [] part2Data = data.split("#");
                parsedData[1] = part2Data[0];
                parsedData[2] = part2Data[1];
                break;
            }
            case 2: parsedData[0] = parsedData[0] + data; break;
            case 3: {
                String [] part4Data = data.split("#");
                parsedData[1] = parsedData[1] + part4Data[0];
                parsedData[2] = parsedData[2] + part4Data[1];
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }
    parsingBlock = -1;
    if (data.equals("part 1")) {
        parsingBlock = 0;
    } else if (data.equals("part 2")) {
        parsingBlock = 1;
    } else if (data.equals("part 3")) {
        parsingBlock = 2;
    } else if (data.equals("part 4")) {
        parsingBlock = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using the contents of the StringBuffer:

```
List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> arr3 = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("part \\d+\\n(.*)\\n+part \\d+\\n(.*)#(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sBuffer);
while(m.find()) {
    arr1.add(m.group(1));
    arr2.add(m.group(2));
    arr3.add(m.group(3));
}
```

Note: In the above code, I have used ArrayLists instead of arrays for convenience. However you can easily convert an `List<String>` into a `String[]` array by using `myList.toArray(new String[0])`.